# Is there a way to delete the last two characters of a string in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, awk

I need to drop the decimal point of the 7th value in a csv file. This is more of a string manipulation question since I wish to retain the leading zeros in the CSV file. So int() is not an option as that it will remove the leading zeros as well. Can anyone help?

myfile.csv contents

```
00014,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-30,7339.jpg,3625.6
00015,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-29,8839.jpg,0030.1
```

output needed

```
00014,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-30,7339.jpg,3625
00015,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-29,8839.jpg,0030
```

Thanks

Comment: I need to drop the decimal and the char that's after that. So the last two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat myfile.csv
00014,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-30,7339.jpg,3625.6
00015,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-29,8839.jpg,0030.1
$ sed -e 's/\..$//' myfile.csv
00014,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-30,7339.jpg,3625
00015,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-29,8839.jpg,0030
$ awk '{sub("\..$","",$7)}1' FS=, OFS=, myfile.csv
00014,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-30,7339.jpg,3625
00015,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-29,8839.jpg,0030
```

If you want to consider the possibility of more than one digit after the decimal point:

```
awk '{sub("\.[0-9]+$","",$7)}1' FS=, OFS=, myfile.csv
sed -E 's/\.[0-9]+$//' myfile.csv
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! The awk statement is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

*This is more of a string manipulation*

Then you might use one of [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) in this case `substr`. Let `file.txt` content be

```
00014,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-30,7339.jpg,3625.6
00015,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-29,8839.jpg,0030.1
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}{$7=substr($7,1,length($7)-2);print}' file.txt
```

output

```
00014,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-30,7339.jpg,3625
00015,0001,some place,user1,2020-04-29,8839.jpg,0030
```

This does simply replace 7th column content with (number of characters - 2) first characters of it, i.e. jettison two last characters.